Dagger Hilt Singleton not instantiated after app is re-launched (After Task Is Removed)
I am new to dagger hilt, but it has been straight to familiarize myself. I am building a Music player application, using Media 3 exoplayer, However, recently I have observed that the app works fine on first launch, but breaks on subsequent launches if the app is closed (removed from recent apps). Here is how my dagger di is defined
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesAudioAttributes(): AudioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setContentType(C.AUDIO_CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
        .setUsage(C.USAGE_MEDIA)
        .build()

    @OptIn(UnstableApi::class)
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideExoPlayer(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context,
        audioAttributes: AudioAttributes,
    ): ExoPlayer {
        Log.d("ExoPlayer", "Creating new instance of ExoPlayer")
        return ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
            .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes, true)
            .setHandleAudioBecomingNoisy(true)
            .setTrackSelector(DefaultTrackSelector(context))
            .build()
    }

I also see following error messages on logcat
Handler (android.os.Handler) {63c3727} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread (Ask Gemini)
         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {63c3727} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
         at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:560)
         at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:786)
         at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:735)
         at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:705)
         at android.os.Handler.sendMessage(Handler.java:643)

NB: The log Creating new instance of ExoPlayer is only seen on app fresh launches, but on subsequent launches, its not visible, meaning its not instantiated again, which it wont work as I had already cleared
@AndroidEntryPoint
class EPlayerSessionService:MediaSessionService() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mediaSession: MediaSession

    @Inject
    lateinit var notificationManager: EPlayerNotificationManager

    @Inject
    lateinit var playerServiceHandler: PlayerServiceHandler

    @Inject
    lateinit var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer

    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
        // Handle cleanup when the task is removed
        if (exoPlayer.playWhenReady) {
            exoPlayer.pause()
        }
        exoPlayer.release()
        mediaSession.release()
        stopSelf()
    }
}

What can I do to fix this?

Your issue is likely due to improper lifecycle management of ExoPlayer. Ensure you initialize and release ExoPlayer properly in your component's lifecycle methods. Also, create a minimal reproducible example and remove any unnecessary code.
